# Shows message in Android Parse "No push notifications to display yet"

Tags: android, parse-platform

Im a beginner in Android Parse technology.I tried a sample app with this link: 
  https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/new

I have followed each steps and successfully run the app on android mobile. But for push when I clicked "send a push" button , that shows message "No registered devices".There is no information is available that how I can register a device .

Thanks 
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Check out this  section of the Parse documentation: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#installations/Android

You need to create an installation for your app on start up. This will register your device for push notifications from your app. If you want to check that a device has been installed, go to your Parse Dashboard and look at the Installations table. The number of rows here will indicate the number of devices that have been registered.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I would like to clarify my question is again.Because  even in the starting of create new application I am facing the probelm.  I tried the all steps under link :    https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/new       And successfully run the app in mobile.  And clicked "Test the SDK". Shows "Can't find any registered devices yet..."

Comment: I would like to clarify my answer again, because you didn't seem to get it. I have looked at the basic code given to you in the blank application. At no point is an installation created, therefore you need to save the devices installation on start up. Read the section of the Parse documentation at the link I posted to find out how to do this.